# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element on trying to upload a file in selenium

Tags: selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload a file in the webpage through selenium webdriver, and i have written the below code

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#collapseDocuments > div > button.button.ng-isolatescope")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\siva.247588\\Desktop\\Clarient+AML+Questionnaire.docx");
```

The CSS selector is that of the browse button.

I am getting the below error whwn i run this:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element

What is wrong with my code? Could any one advise?

Comment: I will recommend AutoIT for file uploads http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/upload-a-file-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoit

Comment: No AutoIT.. Any other suggestion pls?

Comment: To make it work, you need to call `sendKeys` on an `input` element and not a `button`.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to upload a file, the control is shifted to our local machine from website where we were writing scripts.

So normal click method and select method won't work. You can use robot method to browse and upload some file from your local machine to websites.

Hope this help you..

See the below link for help:
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-file-upload-using-robots

I've used this somewhere , hope you can relate this:

Robot rb = new Robot();

```
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);

    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);

    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);

    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    Thread.sleep(4000L);

    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    Thread.sleep(4000L);

    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

This will browse and upload a file with name "Alert"

If you need more help, kindly provide me code and what you want to upload , I'll help you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @theroot mentioned AutoIT is a good solution, but the downside is it works only on windows based platforms. The best solution so far that I have come across for upload or focus outside browser situations is using Sikuli. Example code is below

```
Screen sikuliObject= new Screen();    // Creating Screen class object
Pattern add = new Pattern("path to the image.png");    // Path of the upload button image.
    sikuliObject.click(add);    // Click on Upload button
    Thread.sleep(2000);    // Wait for 2 seconds for upload window pop-up.

    sikuliObject.type("Path of the uploading file and click on enter."+ Key.ENTER );   
    //Path of the uploading file and click on enter.
    Thread.sleep(2000);        // Wait for 2 seconds to load the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've once had a similar problem (I'm not sure anymore if it threw a "not visible" exception or the "could not focus"one) and the problem was that the input Element wasn't accessible because it had no dimensions. I've changed the DOM information using the JavaScriptExecuter and afterwards it worked fine. Just go through your page with Firebug and look if the element is really visible.